# regex for preg_match_all() for scraping specific URL cases

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match-all

I need to parse HTML to extract an array of URLs like:

```
<a href="/article/Social-Security-Disability-Why-Should-I-Hire-an-Attorney/3702266/"
```

What I'd like out of it is an array like:

- [0] = /article/Social-Security-Disability-Why-Should-I-Hire-an-Attorney/3702266/
- [1] = /article/Social-Security-Disability-And-Fibromyalgia/3960799/
- [2] = /article/Social-Security-Disability-Appeals-Why-You-Need-An-Advocate-At-Your-Hearing/4961868/

I'm hoping to do it in regex, but any method that actually works is fine.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try and have a look at `$result`

```
preg_match_all('/<a href="([^"]*)"/', $urls, $result);
```

Comment: Close!  I only want /article/ URLs, so I modified it to be: preg_match_all('/<a href="\/article([^"]*)"/', $urls, $result); but I don't want the result array to include any chars except for what I list in my question, so no "<a href=".  Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: have u tried this solution? this regex should not include `<a href="` in result. only chars catched by `([^"]*)` are included in result